# Can I learn someone's IP address by Skype text chat?

Tags: skype, ip-address

It may be possible to learn on voice or cam conversation but is it possible by text chat? If so how can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is possible then you can see partner's ip in connection list generated by your firewall or use *netstat -b*. But I am not sure if Skype use direct connection to your partner when you send text message.

Comment: if the partner runs a skype in a supernode mode (skype is P2P; so he gets the traffic), generally having ports 80/443 open - it can be traced in netstat. But you don't know, it that supernode his. Supernode option can be blocked/turned off, too, and don't know is not-supernode ip visible.